# Having trouble with opencv on C++ project vsCode

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to C++ (and C) but I have some backgrounds in programming.

I am using opencv to do some computer vision codes.

I am using cmake to compile my code.

I have a dedicated include file with all my `.h` files.

I want to have a modular approach so that I can easily maintain my files.

I have set properly the environnement variables.

I don't understand: why do I have the following errors? Could you
give me some good rules of thumb for a beginner to solve these errors as fast as posible?

here are my Env Variables:

[image: myEnvVariables]

and here is where i installed it:

[image: location]

Here are my codes

```
// src/streams/input/videoInput.c
#include "C:/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2highgui.hpp"
#include "C:/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;

void SetVideo() {
    string windowName = "Video Input";
    namedWindow( windowName, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    if( !cap.isOpened() ) {
        printf("Could not initialize capturing...\n");
        return;
    }
    Mat frame;
    while( 1 ) {
        cap >> frame;
        if( !frame.data ) break; // Ran out of film
    imshow( windowName, frame );
    if( waitKey(33) >= 0 ) break;
       }
       system("pause");
    return 0;
}
// include/videoInput.h
#ifndef VideoInput_h__
#define VideoInput_h__

void SetVideo();

#endif // VideoInput_h__
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../includes/videoInput.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

     printf("Hello World\n");
     SetVideo();
     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

I am expecting to be able to execute SetVideo() when ever I call it.
I wonder if there is a way to create some sort of a task in vscode that
could generate my .h files and update my makefile for me automatically ?

Comment: Why do you want to generate header files? What are you generating them from?

Comment: Using absolute paths to include opencv header file (like this `#include "C:/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"`) shows that your setup is not correct. That include should be `#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>` and if that is not working then you need to fix that problem, not use a different `#include`.

Comment: I am used to work on vue js and in vue there are some lines of code that you can add to your main.js file to make vue automatically import and unimport your components so you don't have to do it yourself. I was wondering if it is possible to do something similar but to create the .h files linked to my future c files

Comment: @KarljoY973 C++ programmers are used to writing .cpp and .h files in parallel, it's not ideal but you get used to it. Modern C++ has a feature called *modules* which I believe avoids the need to have separate .cpp and .h files, but I can't say I know much about it.

Comment: The code is not C, please read [tag:c] carefully: *C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag without a specific reason.*

Comment: trying to use an advanced library like OpenCV is ***not recommended for beginners***. you need to learn how C++ code needs to be structured first (.cpp and .hpp files, what the compiler and linker make of these, etc). -- OpenCV does not exist for C. If you want to ditch C++, you can always use Python. Python has many advantages to a beginner.

Comment: I understand but it is actually a school project and I have to use opencv, but thanks for the explanation, I will set up a c++ project properly.

Answer (score 0):

im done :( I will try to reinstall everything, and pray day and night till it works